# How do I reference the instance of tbb::task_group_context which is being passed in through the tbb::parallel_for loop

Tags: c++, tbb

```
tbb::task_group_context tg;
SomeClass someObject;

tbb:: parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0, num, grainSize), 
                   someObject,
                   tbb::simple_partitioner(),
                   tg);
```

```
class SomeClass
{
void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r)  const
{

   tg.cancel_group_execution();
   //how do i refer to object tg ?
}
```

I get the following build error: `"tg" not declared in this scope`.
How is it using the passed in `tg` variable?

Answer (score 0):

oneTBB supports [Exceptions and Cancellation](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneTBB/main/tbb_userguide/Exceptions_and_Cancellation.html), that means you just have to throw an exception from `SomeClass::operator()` and cancellation will be automatic...
You may also [Cancel without exceptions](https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneTBB/main/tbb_userguide/Cancellation_Without_An_Exception.html) by just calling `tbb::current_context()->cancel_group_execution()`.